# How do I filter DataFrame columns where a field is contained in a given string?

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe "df" with column "X", and I want to filter rows whose X field contains "foo":

```
df2 = df[df['X'].str.contains('foo', na=False)]
```

For instance a row where X is "foow" will match. Now suppose I want to filter rows where the X field is *contained* in "foo", e.g. "fo". How do I do this as efficiently as possible?

I tried doing a manual loop, e.g.

```
df2 = DataFrame([row for _,row in df.iterrows() if row['X'] in 'foo'])
```

But this is slow and I'm wondering if there's a built-in method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `apply()` function, which (in my test) is twice as fast:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['fo', 'foo', 'fooo'], 'b': ['bar', 'bar', 'bar']})
%timeit df_test[df_test['a'].apply(lambda x: x in 'foo')]
```

187 µs ± 2.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame([row for _,row in df_test.iterrows() if row['a'] in 'foo'])
```

337 µs ± 10 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)